# Populating Select Box based on ID - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables, `schools` and `grades` and they are many to many related. I have successfully set up the many to many relationships in the model already.

I am able to insert the select box value into the database but i having difficulty try to fetch.

When i click on a grade with `id = 1` for instance, i am trying to fetch its corresponding school into the select box including the values.  i get an error `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`.

What am i not doing right in my query?

**controller**

```
public function editPage($id)
    {
        $grade = Grade::whereId($id)->firstorFail(); 
        $schools = $grade->schools()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        return view('grades.edit',compact('grade','schools'));

    }
```

**Model**

```
public function schools()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\School')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">School</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control" id="school" name="school[]" mulitple>
@foreach($schools as $school)
<option value="{!! $school->id !!}" @if(in_array($school->id, $schools)) selected="selected" @endif >
               {!! $schools->name !!}
</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have 2 id columns in the returning view. How is your relationship defined?

Comment: many to many relationship. I set them up in each model

Comment: Can you show us the implementation? At what line exactly do you get that error?

Comment: @wast, please look at the implementation of the Grade.php Model. I did like wise for School.php Model relating to grade()

Comment: Have a look at my view

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably because it's not sure what 'id' you want to pluck.

Try

```
    $schools = $grade->schools()->pluck('schools.id')->toArray();
```

You could also just pass the grade and get the schools in the view...

```
public function editPage($id)
{
    $grade = Grade::whereId($id)->with('schools')->firstorFail();
    return view('grades.edit', compact('grade'));
}
```

And then

```
$school_options = $grade->schools->pluck('name', 'id');

@foreach($school_options->all() as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: trying to get property of a non-object in my blade.php. That's the error showing up. Is it because of the array?

Comment: Please have a look at my view. I tried your update but i still get the same error  `trying to get property of a non-object in my blade.php`

Comment: Yer, where you have this $school->id that's looking for the id on an object but your $school is an array because you set it to be toArray(). So you an try remove the toArray() or just change it to $school['id']

Comment: The error doesn't show up anymore but then my select box is empty

Comment: I edited my answer, see if that helps. I rushed my reply so I am not sure it was 100%. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

`$school` is an array in your case, so your view most likely can't decide what to do with `$school->id`...
Seems more likely you wanna just use school models in your view, so just only `compact('grade')` and then use `foreach($grade->schools as $school)` in your view.
Also your conditional for selected options seems wrong, every `$school` (which is only an id at this point, because `$schools` is an array of ids) is obviously in `$schools` because that's how your foreach is set up. But you should fix the other thing first.

Comment: I don't understand your statement please

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I am trying to understand every part of your statement because i have other select boxes using the same foreach loop and they work fine when retrieving data